# jsondata error '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Tags: json, flutter, api

How can I get information from this code Jason I don't know what the problem is?
I tried to get the total at the end of Jason's code and the information inside the data, but it shows me this error.

**the error**

```
GetLogsData error is: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'
```

**here is the jonData**
i wanna get data and total from logs object

```
{
    "logs": {
        "data": [
            {
                "description": "Failed Login Attempt",
                "created_at": "2022-07-21T13:58:49.000000Z"
            }
          ],
        "total": 21
    },
    "totalLogs": 21
}
```

**here is the code:**

in here getting the logs

```
Future GetLogsData() async {
  try {
    var response = await CallApi().getData('logs');
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    List<_LogsList> Logs_List = [];
    for (var index in jsonResponse) {
      _LogsList logsList = _LogsList(
        data: index['data'] ?? '',
        total: index['total'] ?? '',
      );
      Logs_List.add(logsList);
    }
    
    return Logs_List;
  }catch (e) {
    print('GetLogsData error is: $e');
    return[];
  }
}
```

**this is storeing list**

```
class _LogsList {
  final dynamic total;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> data;
  _LogsList( {this.total, this.data, });


}
```

Comment: Your code is not visible. Share your code, to know more in brief.

Comment: @PratulPant witch part of code do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you should first create a `Log` class with ` factory method, this way you'll be able to easily generate a list of logs. Follow these steps,

Step 1 : Create a `Log` class

```dart
class Log {
  final String description, createdAt;

  const Log({
    required this.description,
    required this.createdAt,
  });

  factory Log.fromData(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return Log(
      description: data['description'],
      createdAt: data['created_at'],
    );
  }
}
```

Step 2 : Decode the response and convert it to a list of logs

```dart
final data = json.decode(response.body);

final List<Log> logs = data['logs']['data']
  .map<Log>((logData) => Log.fromData(logData))
  .toList();
```

After this, based on your code, you can choose to create an extra `LogList` class or can directly extract total number of logs, but the base should be this, Good luck!

Comment: thanks
but I got some trouble with null data in logs

Answer (score 2):

I think your json has extra coma in it. It should have to look like this.

```
{
    "logs": {
        "data": [
            {
                "description": "Failed Login Attempt",
                "created_at": "2022-07-21T13:58:49.000000Z"
            }
          ],
        "total": 21
    },
    "totalLogs": 21
}
```

Comment: it was my fault
The json data was too long
I deleted some of his data